# How can I make an "input" that allows you to enter only vowel letters? Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, input, text

How can I make an "input" that allows you to enter only vowel letters?
Copying, dragging text into the input field should also be filtered.

```
<div class="field">
        <input class="field_word" type="text">
    </div>
const field = document.querySelector('.field');
        const fieldWord = document.querySelector('.field_word');

        fieldWord.onkeypress = (event) => {
            if ((event.keyCode > 48) || (event.keyCode < 90)) {
            event.preventDefault();
```

Comment: you can use replace with a regex expression to remove all other characters besides vowel characters

Answer (score 2):

You can use the function below to filter your input to a certain set of characters:

```js
// Restricts input for the given textbox element to the given inputFilter.
    function setInputFilter(textbox, inputFilter) {
      ["input", "keydown", "keyup", "mousedown", "mouseup", "select", "contextmenu", "drop"].forEach(function(event) {
        textbox.addEventListener(event, function() {
          if (inputFilter(this.value)) {
            this.oldValue = this.value;
            this.oldSelectionStart = this.selectionStart;
            this.oldSelectionEnd = this.selectionEnd;
          } else if (this.hasOwnProperty("oldValue")) {
            this.value = this.oldValue;
            this.setSelectionRange(this.oldSelectionStart, this.oldSelectionEnd);
          } else {
            this.value = "";
          }
        });
      });
    }
    
    
    // Example USE: Install input filters.
    setInputFilter(document.getElementById("vowelTextbox"), function(value) {
      return /^[aioueAIOUE]*$/i.test(value); 
    });
```

```html
<h2>JS input filter vowels</h2>
<p>
  Supports Copy+Paste, Drag+Drop, keyboard shortcuts, context menu operations, 
  non-typeable keys, the caret position, different keyboard layouts, 
  and all browsers since IE 9 
</p>

<input id="vowelTextbox">
```

NOTE: Snippet taken and edited from this [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/emkey08/zgvtjc51)